# Empty result when copying files with Java

Tags: java, file, copy

I'm trying to "rename" a folder with my application copying the source folder to another.

But... When I create the destination folder, the files inside it are empty (0 bytes).
Notice that this happens only on the linux machine where I deploy the app. 
Doesn't happens on my local machine with windows.

I've tried

```
Files.copy(src, dest);
```

and creating the byte array with input/output streams

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

Same result.
Any ideas?

Comment: Rights? As what user do you run it and which user owns the files?

Comment: Can you provide a short, self contained example we can run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why this problem occurs on the Linux machine, what VM and Version is running on the Linux machine?

You might want to try apache commons-io FileUtils it has copyDirectory methods, makes live much easier.

http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to rename then u must be using the method `Files.move` instead.

But still `Files.copy` should also work fine. I'll better if you post more of your code to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On its own `Files.copy` only works for files not for directories.

You have to use `Files.walkFileTree`.

I've wrote some utility methods for this (the library is Open Source).

Tutorial:
http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/0.2/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html

Maven:

```
<dependency>   
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>   
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>   
    <version>0.2</version>    
</dependency>
```

More info:

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2012/07/news-from-software-smithy-version-02.html